# EPERM error using nanogen when rebuilding project

Tags: node.js

I am using https://github.com/doug2k1/nanogen and I can build the project, a `public` folder gets created and files get transferred successfully however the generator has a option for live refresh which does not work because of the EPERM error, what can I do to fix it? I am on Windows
I tried:

- Creating the public folder myself
- Deleting the node modules while the server is not running and re installing
- Running the build command as admin